# How to calculate a combination of convolution and correlation by FFT?

Tags: fft, correlation, convolution

I'm trying to achieve an algorithm to efficiently calculate a combination of convolution and correlation such as following :

```
c(x,y)=(sum of i, (sum of j, a(x-i,y+j)*b(i,j)))
```

I have known that 1-D convolution or correlation can be solved by

```
a conv b = ifft(fft(a).*fft(b))
a corr b = ifft(fft(a).*conjg(fft(b)))
```

But I have no idea about the combination of them in 2-D or N-D problems. I think it is similar to 2-D convolution, but I don't know the specific deduction process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlation can be written in terms of the convolution by reversing one of the arguments:

```
corr(x(t),y(t)) = conv(x(t),y(-t))
```

Thus, if you want the x-axis to behave like a convolution and the y-axis to behave like a correlation, reverse the y-axis only and compute the convolution. It doesn’t matter if you use a spatial or frequency domain implementation.